# gfortran ABI backward compatibility on OSX

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran, abi

For C and C++ on OSX, `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6` and `--mmacosx-version-min=10.6` can be use to build a program/library that can run on OSX 10.6 or greater.

Is there any such functionality for Fortran? I plan to install Fortran from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/, and to call Fortran functions from C.